# JavaScript execution sequence for given code not understandable

Tags: javascript

I ran the following code in my console:

```
    let a3 = 100;
    setTimeout( function(){
            a3 = a3 + 1;
            console.log(a3);
        }, 4000);

     console.log( ++a3+'st');
```

I do not understand the execution sequence of the above JavaScript Code.

I expected the output to be

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT

101st     //since console.log(++a3+'st') executes first
101st1   //the setTimeout() function executes
```

But the actual output I got is

```
ACTUAL OUTPUT

101st
102
```

I want to understand that, if `a3` becomes a string `"101st"` after `console.log( ++a3+'st');` runs, then why does the code inside `setTimeout()`

```
setTimeout( function(){
        a3 = a3 + 1;
        console.log(a3);
    }, 4000);
```

which runs later, give `a3` as `102` and not `101st1` since `"101st" + 1 = "101st1"` ?

Comment: You don't set or assign `a3` with 'st'. You simply increment it, string append and logs it when you do `console.log( ++a3+'st');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if `a3` becomes a string "101st" after `console.log( ++a3+'st');` runs

It doesn't. All that statement does for `a3` is it *increments it by one* via the `++a3` part. That is then concatenated with `st`, resulting in a string which is `console.log`ged, *but not saved anywhere* - `a3` remains the incremented number.

For `a3` to become the string, you would have to explicitly assign the result to `a3`:

```js
let a3 = 100;
setTimeout(function() {
  a3 = a3 + 1;
  console.log(a3);
}, 500);

console.log(a3 = ++a3 + 'st');
```

(but please don't do something like that - assignments should not be parsed as expressions, it's quite a code smell)

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down the code

The following is synchronous code and will execute immediately hence writing `(++100+'st')`=>`(101+'st')`=>`101st` in console

```
 let a3 = 100;
 ...
 console.log( ++a3+'st');
```

The `setTimeout` is an asynchronous block of code and will execute after the synchronous code has been executed, since `a3` is now `101`, `a3+1` will output `102`

```
setTimeout( function(){
  a3 = a3 + 1;
  console.log(a3);
}, 4000);
```

hence you get the output

```
101st
102
```

Answer (score 0):

What is actually fine. When you are calling this `console.log( ++a3+'st');` It only increases it to 101 but not to `101st` use this

```
let a3 = 100;
    setTimeout( function(){
            a3 = a3 + 1;
            console.log(a3);
        }, 4000);
a3 = (a3 + 1) + 'st'
console.log(a3);
```